# Текст поверх слайдера

Tags: html, css, slider

Есть слайдер. Мне нужно чтобы у меня был текст на слайдах и иконки различного типа : [image: как на этой картинке] и когда я вместо цифр 1,2,3,4 пишу текст и с новой строки еще раз текст, то он пропадает.
CSS:

```
.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slider__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.slider__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.slider__control {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.slider__control:hover,
.slider__control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slider__control_left {
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slider__control_right {
  right: 0;
}
.slider__control::before {
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.slider__control_left::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.slider__control_right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.slider__item>div {
  line-height: 250px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 293px; background: orange;">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 293px; background: green;">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 293px; background: violet;">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 293px; background: coral;">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ADDED A WRAPPER DIV -->
    <div class="slider__controls">
      <a class="slider__control slider__control_left" href="#" role="button"></a>
      <a class="slider__control slider__control_right slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Я не знаю почему он пропадает. Как это решить?
Вот ссылка на полный код вместе с JS: https://jsfiddle.net/13fowgvt/2/

Comment: Возможно, он просто не помещается в слайдер? Цифры то очень большие и вторая строка вряд ли может поместиться на слайдере.

Comment: @Eleferen я изменил `font-size`, но все равно не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст убегал потому что у вас `height` была `250px` и `line-height` тоже `250px` для даного блока.

Убрал с `.slider__item>div{line-height: 250px;}` и добавил класс `.slid`. а далее уже `flex` выровнял текст внутри блока.

```js
'use strict';
    var multiItemSlider = (function () {
      return function (selector, config) {
        var
          _mainElement = document.querySelector(selector), // основный элемент блока
          _sliderWrapper = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__wrapper'), // обертка для .slider-item
          _sliderItems = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), // элементы (.slider-item)
          _sliderControls = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), // элементы управления
          _sliderControlLeft = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_left'), // кнопка "LEFT"
          _sliderControlRight = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_right'), // кнопка "RIGHT"
          _wrapperWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderWrapper).width), // ширина обёртки
          _itemWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderItems[0]).width), // ширина одного элемента    
          _positionLeftItem = 0, // позиция левого активного элемента
          _transform = 0, // значение транфсофрмации .slider_wrapper
          _step = _itemWidth / _wrapperWidth * 100, // величина шага (для трансформации)
          _items = [], // массив элементов
          _interval = 0,
          _config = {
            isCycling: false, // автоматическая смена слайдов
            direction: 'right', // направление смены слайдов
            interval: 5000, // интервал между автоматической сменой слайдов
            pause: true // устанавливать ли паузу при поднесении курсора к слайдеру
          };

        for (var key in config) {
          if (key in _config) {
            _config[key] = config[key];
          }
        }

        // наполнение массива _items
        _sliderItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
          _items.push({ item: item, position: index, transform: 0 });
        });

        var position = {
          getItemMin: function () {
            var indexItem = 0;
            _items.forEach(function (item, index) {
              if (item.position < _items[indexItem].position) {
                indexItem = index;
              }
            });
            return indexItem;
          },
          getItemMax: function () {
            var indexItem = 0;
            _items.forEach(function (item, index) {
              if (item.position > _items[indexItem].position) {
                indexItem = index;
              }
            });
            return indexItem;
          },
          getMin: function () {
            return _items[position.getItemMin()].position;
          },
          getMax: function () {
            return _items[position.getItemMax()].position;
          }
        }

        var _transformItem = function (direction) {
          var nextItem;
          if (direction === 'right') {
            _positionLeftItem++;
            if ((_positionLeftItem + _wrapperWidth / _itemWidth - 1) > position.getMax()) {
              nextItem = position.getItemMin();
              _items[nextItem].position = position.getMax() + 1;
              _items[nextItem].transform += _items.length * 100;
              _items[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _items[nextItem].transform + '%)';
            }
            _transform -= _step;
          }
          if (direction === 'left') {
            _positionLeftItem--;
            if (_positionLeftItem < position.getMin()) {
              nextItem = position.getItemMax();
              _items[nextItem].position = position.getMin() - 1;
              _items[nextItem].transform -= _items.length * 100;
              _items[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _items[nextItem].transform + '%)';
            }
            _transform += _step;
          }
          _sliderWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transform + '%)';
        }

        var _cycle = function (direction) {
          if (!_config.isCycling) {
            return;
          }
          _interval = setInterval(function () {
            _transformItem(direction);
          }, _config.interval);
        }

        // обработчик события click для кнопок "назад" и "вперед"
        var _controlClick = function () {
          var direction = this.classList.contains('slider__control_right') ? 'right' : 'left';
          _transformItem(direction);
          clearInterval(_interval);
          _cycle(_config.direction);
        };

        var _setUpListeners = function () {
          // добавление к кнопкам "назад" и "вперед" обрботчика _controlClick для событя click
          _sliderControls.forEach(function (item) {
            item.addEventListener('click', _controlClick);
          });
          if (_config.pause && _config.isCycling) {
            _mainElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
              clearInterval(_interval);
            });
            _mainElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
              clearInterval(_interval);
              _cycle(_config.direction);
            });
          }
        }

        // инициализация
        _setUpListeners();
        _cycle(_config.direction);

        return {
          right: function () { // метод right
            _transformItem('right');
          },
          left: function () { // метод left
            _transformItem('left');
          },
          stop: function () { // метод stop
            _config.isCycling = false;
            clearInterval(_interval);
          },
          cycle: function () { // метод cycle 
            _config.isCycling = true;
            clearInterval(_interval);
            _cycle();
          }
        }

      }
    }());

    var slider = multiItemSlider('.slider', {
      isCycling: true
    })
```

```css
/*код который добавил*/
.slider__item .slid{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/*END*/

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  /* ADDED: */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slider__item {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Added: */
.slider__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.slider__control {
  /* Added: */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Updated: */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  /* The Same: */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  /*
    REMOVED: transform: translateY(-50%);
  */
}

.slider__control:hover,
.slider__control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slider__control_left {
  left: 0;
  /* Added: */
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slider__control_right {
  right: 0;
}
.slider__control::before {
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.slider__control_left::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.slider__control_right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
      <div class="slider__item">
      <div style="height: 250px; background: orange;" class="slid">
       <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: green;" class="slid">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: violet;" class="slid">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: coral;" class="slid">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ADDED A WRAPPER DIV -->
    <div class="slider__controls">
      <a class="slider__control slider__control_left" href="#" role="button"></a>
      <a class="slider__control slider__control_right slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам. Последний вопрос: я сделал величину шага не 100, а 200, но тогда цикла исчез, то есть после 4 слайда не идет снова 1 а идет белый фон. не знаете из-за чего это?

Comment: Потому что при увеличении `_wrapperWidth` вы увеличиваете ширину `// ширина обёртки` а сами елементы `_itemWidth // ширина одного элемента`остаются без изменения

Comment: окей, спасибо за помощь!